# Non-linear system of equations with a parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve

```
k*x-(x-y)*y^2==0
```

and

```
y+(x-y)*y^2-(1-x-y)==0
```

for `-10 < k <10`

How do I tell Mathematica to solve it and give me the results in a table?

Comment: Try googling for "mathematica solve equation" then for "mathematica table".  Please, before asking for others' time to solve your problem, at least show that you have tried to do it on your own first.

Comment: i have tried a lot using while and NSolve[], i got the results but i want them in a txt file in order to use them in fortran. Excuse me i didn't know i have to tell all the history...

Comment: (1) Every line of code you supply is, potentially , a line others do not need to write. (2) It is helpful to know in advance the full context. In this case, the fact that results are wanted in a txt file is important and should be noted in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
sol=Assuming[
 -10 < k < 10,
 Simplify@Solve[
   And @@ {
     k*x - (x - y)*y^2 == 0,
     y + (x - y)*y^2 - (1 - x - y) == 0
     }, {x, y}]
 ];
```

that is the analytical solution (there are three). You can evaluate that numerically

```
dat=Transpose@Table[Chop@N[{x, y} /. sol], {k, -10, 10, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[dat]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

empty regions are complex

Comment: That Chop@N looks almost...musical.